# Query from one platform in a different platform using Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, dataframe

I am looking for a way to query from one machine (client) in another machine (remote client) in Scala. A query like this:

```
   df1 = sql(s"select * from database.table_name")
```

where the table and its database are in a different platform.

Any suggestion or solution?

Comment: why does this get negative votes!? I have done this in Python but I am looking for a way to do it Scala.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because it's a little too broad. There are a number of steps involved in setting up this type of communication. I hope my question helps. If I can clarify further, please let me know!

Comment: Also if you could post the code you've tried so far, others could help identify the specific issue.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. I am looking into yours to deploy it in my code. Still working on it and if it's worked I would mark it. I haven't tried any code myslef. The one I have in python is using "paramiko".

Comment: Cool! Looks like Paramiko is a Secure Shell server/client for Python. That may provide the _security_ layer for a client-to-DB connection, but it can't provide any of the functionality for actually querying the database. If jooq and the other options fail you, it might be necessary to layer on some SSH configuration.

Comment: True, as long as the connection is made using Paramiko, then using "hive -e; the query" I can get the data. Paramiko give the access through passwork and username. Your answer is a bit broad and the links are mostly in Java. Is it possible for you to provide more codes there in Scala?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199854/discussion-between-michael-crenshaw-and-alan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Connecting via SSH**

In comments you mentioned you've used Paramiko (a Python SSH client) and `hive -e; the query` to accomplish your goal.

If you'd like to follow that same route, you can use [scala-ssh](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-ssh#usage) to connect to the remote device and execute queries using your preferred local DB client.

In your case, it might look something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053824/ssh-using-scala-with-username-and-password):

```
SSH(
  "your-server.com", 
  HostConfig(PasswordLogin("username", PasswordProducer.fromString("password")))
) { client =>
  for {
    result <- client.exec("hive -e; the query")
  } println("Result:\n" + result.stdOutAsString())
}
```

**Connecting via DB Client**

A more robust solution is to connect directly to the remote database with a DB client. There are a number of libraries you can use in Scala. One popular library is [jooq](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-scala/). There's an [article outlining a few other scala database access options](https://medium.com/@takezoe/database-access-libraries-in-scala-7aa7590aa3db).

Once you've picked a client library, you need to connect to the MySQL server. If you already have one set up, consult the database administrator for connection information. If you don't already have one set up, investigate how to set up a MySQL instance.

You can glance over basic database connection examples here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step4/

This line is where you would set the database admin-provided server details:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";
```

Many of the examples are in Java, but they translate easily to Scala once you know the differences/similarities.